# Issue with clock

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting such request to be solved:

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Create a clock application written in Python that will print the following values at the following intervals to stdout:

- "tick" every second
- "tock" every minute
- "bong" every hour

Only one value should be printed in a given second, i.e. when printing "bong" on the hour, the "tick" and "tock" values should not be printed.

It should run for three hours and then exit.

A mechanism should exist for the user to alter any of the printed values while the program is running, i.e. after the clock has run for 10 minutes I should, without stopping the program, be able to change it so that it stops printing "tick" every second and starts printing "quack" instead.

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I think I was able to correctly write this:

==============================================================================
- "tick" every second

- "tock" every minute
- "bong" every hour

Only one value should be printed in a given second, i.e. when printing "bong" on the hour, the "tick" and "tock" values should not be printed.

It should run for three hours and then exit.

```
for k in range (3): # 3 hours
 for j in range(60): # one hour
  for i in range(60):
   print('Tick',i, j)
   time.sleep(1)
  for i in range(1):
   print('Tock',i, j)
   time.sleep(1)
 for j in range(1):
      print('Bong',j)
      time.sleep(1)
```

but how to write:

=============================================================================
A mechanism should exist for the user to alter any of the printed values while the program is running, i.e. after the clock has run for 10 minutes I should, without stopping the program, be able to change it so that it stops printing "tick" every second and starts printing "quack" instead.

Comment: You are basically asking "how to pass data to my program". This highly depends on how your program is run. Is it launched via a terminal, such as Linux bash or Windows cmd? Is it an executable file that user execute via a GUI? Is it run as part of another application? Are users aware/able to use command line arguments, configuration files, environment variables?

Comment: I write it normally from IDLE lik

Comment: The matter is how the application is to be *run by the user*, not how you wrote it.

Comment: I think from command line in windows . F

Comment: this is standalone script in Python, no any other apps involved

Comment: Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Have a look at the ``argparse`` module, the ``click`` library, the ``sys.argv`` member, the ``os.environ`` mapping, the ``open`` builtin - there are tons of ways to solve this. If you want *one* you have to be more precise with your question.

Comment: could you confirm which comment to be precised?

Comment: please find queries:
**- how to prevent clock from stopping while user can  change? **"A mechanism should exist for the user to alter any of the printed values while the program is running, i.e. after the clock has run for 10 minutes I should, without stopping the program, be able to change it so that it stops printing "tick" every second and starts printing "quack" instead."
-

Comment: when I run my code above, how I can take data from user without stopping code?

Comment: There are still lots of answers to this question; which one is correct depends entirely on details you have not stated. What mechanism have you learned about in your course? What are you allowed or expected to use? Threads, Coroutines, Files, Pipes, Sockets, ...?

Comment: program will be running from IDLE, anything can be used. User will enter some data for example "quack" during running program. I need to capture it and and display "quack" from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`input` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to query the user for a single-line string. This blocks until the input is provided:

```
start = time.time()
value = input('type a line: ')  # wait for input from user
end = time.time()
print('You wrote', repr(value), 'after', end - start, 'seconds.')
```

Since your output must be provided without interruption, blocking for input is not acceptable. You can use the [`threading` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to separate your program into two parts which cannot block each other.

One thread queries the user for time indicators, the other prints the indicator appropriate for the current time. Since your program is simple, you can use a plain type such as `dict` to exchange data between the two parts.

```
indicators = {'second': 'tick', 'minute': 'tock', 'hour': 'bong'}
```

Now for the printing part. `threading` expects a function, so we must define one. It takes our `indicators` to *read from* it. Instead of separate hour, minute, second loops, we track only seconds but calculate whether an hour or minute has passed.

```
import time

def indicate_time(indicators: dict):
    for tick in range(60 * 60 * 3):  # three hours total time
        if tick % 60 * 60 == 0:
           print(indicators['hour'])
        elif tick % 60 == 0:
           print(indicators['minute'])
        else:
           print(indicators['second'])
        time.sleep(1)
```

As for the input part, we need to decide how to query the user. For example, we could use a two-stage input to ask for a category (`seconds`) and then the new indicator (`TICK`). The simplest case is just to ask for all indicators with a separator between them.

We must define another function (or use the main thread) for the input. It takes `indicators` to *write to* it. We use `input` to ask for three values, separated by spaces, as new indicators for seconds, minutes and hours.

```
def update_indicators(indicators: dict):
    message = ''
    while True:
         try:
             indicators['second'], indicators['minute'], indicators['hour'] = \
                 input(message).split()
         except ValueError:  # got an incorrect number of arguments
             message = 'Indicator for second, minute and hour separated by spaces: '
         else:
             message = ''
```

You can then start each part in a Thread. The printing thread should keep your program alive, whereas the input thread should abort with the rest. Instead of running the printing in a new thread, you can also run it in the main thread.

```
import threading

input_thread = threading.Thread(
    target=update_indicators,
    args=(indicators,),
    daemon=True,
)
input_thread.start()
indicate_time(indicators) # run the printer in the main thread
```

Comment: I appreciate response. checking this

Comment: Unfortunately there is an issue I pasted above, not sure how to put below.

Comment: Did you actually press Enter after writing the new symbols?

Comment: yes, after entering values I press 'enter' on keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I combined all above in single program. It runs not quite ok.

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\Users\marcin.idzik\Downloads\Kultura_Czytanie (1) (4)\Kultura_Czytanie (1)\clock.py 
bong 
 Indicator for second, minute and hour separated by spaces: 0fd dsf ggs


 RESTART: C:\Users\marcin.idzik\Downloads\Kultura_Czytanie (1) (4)\Kultura_Czytanie (1)\clock.py 
bong

Indicator for second, minute and hour separated by spaces: kj ke
tickIndicator for second, minute and hour separated by spaces: 
kk ti aza
tick
```

when user provide new values:

```
Indicator for second, minute and hour separated by spaces: 
kk ti aza
```

so now:

```
kk ti aza
```

should be taken and replace 'minute',' second', ' hour' values accordingly:

```
indicators = {'second': 'tick', 'minute': 'tock', 'hour': 'bong'}
```

Right now after user enter new values, still old ones are shown:

```
kk ti aza
tick
```

Comment: Anyone has ideas about this?